# xpages: how to simulate form's auto launch properties

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Is there a quick and easy way to convert forms that have auto launch first attachment and/or launch URL?

I know it can be coded in SSJS but I was just wandering if someone had a quick way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following Domino URL command will open an attachment ...

```
http://Host/DatabaseName/View/DocumentName/$File/fileattachmentname
```

... where the DocumentName is effectively the lookup value shown in the first column which is sorted.

Add an xp:link control and code it open the attachment (in this example in a new window).  For example, the following is an xp:link that could be added in an xp:viewColumn or xp:repeat or any iterator control.  In this example the var for the iterator is set to "rowData" and the name for the link is returned from the ListName column and the url to launch the attachment is in the cLinkUrl column.

```
    <xp:link escape="true" id="link1" target="_blank">
        <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("ListName");}]]></xp:this.text>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("cLinkUrl")}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I wanted the code to be in the xpage, as it opens up either the document or the attachment depending on roles, I ended up adding this to the beforepageload event of the xpage (still need to add the role check to this though):

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
        <xp:executeScript>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var url = currentDocument.getDocument().getHttpURL();
    var attachmentName = @AttachmentNames();
    facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(url.replace("?OpenDocument","/$File/"+attachmentName+"?OpenElement&target=_new"));}]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:executeScript>
       </xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```